# Ajax query not sending request to server

Tags: php, ajax, apache, jquery

I'm working on adding some Ajax to a web page that I have using jQuery. Note that I'm new to Ajax. The page is a simple registration form, and I want to check if the email address the user supplies is already registered, and tell the user if it is, before the form redirects to registration code.

I've been reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362430/ajax-call-to-check-duplicate-data) and its answers, and experimenting to reproduce the effect, but without success.

When I click on submit, the javascript function is called (I've proven this by adding some diagnostic code into the `checkEmail()` function), however when I check my Apache server logs, I can see all the requests that I'm expecting, except for the call to `/user/process/chechemail.php`. The code (below) is located in the `/user/` directory, I've modified the `url:` path with all variations of relative and absolute paths. Nothing is recorded in the Apache error log.

When the user clicks the submit button, they see the message "Something went wrong!". Can anyone spot what is wrong?

The code I have is as follows:

```
<script>
    function checkEmail()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data:
            {
                email: $('#email').val()
            },
            url: "/user/process/checkemail.php"
        })
        .done(function(response)
        {
            $('#message').html(response);
        })
        .fail(function()
        {
            $('#message').html("Something went wrong!");
            return false;
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="register-form">
    <form name="register" action="process/register.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkEmail();">
        <div class="register-email-cell">
            <p class="text">Email Address</p>
        </div>
        <div class="register-email-cell">
            <input class="input" type="text" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="register-email-cell">
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Register">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="message" class="text"></p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Notes:

- The `<script>` reference to jQuery is in a PHP include, not shown above
- /user/process/checkemail.php - looks for $_REQUEST['email'], and performs a query against the database and returns a string stating either 'Email address exists' or 'Email address available' - I realise that this might allow bots to harvest email addresses, but this is just sample code used for my own learning. - It isn't going to be production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checkEmail()` function returns `undefined` immediately, which does not prevent the form from submitting. Your page gets reloaded before the AJAX request has the chance to even start. AJAX requests are asynchronous — they run in the background, and their callbacks are executed outside of the control flow surrounding the actual call to `$.ajax()`, and the callbacks' return values are discarded.

One way to accomplish what you're trying to do, is to have the `done` callback set a flag if the check is successful and submit the form again, and have the `checkEmail()` function return `false` if the flag is not set:

```
var emailChecked = false;
function checkEmail()
{
    if (emailChecked) {
        return true;
    }
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data:
        {
            email: $('#email').val()
        },
        url: "/user/process/checkemail.php"
    })
    .done(function(response)
    {
        $('#message').html(response);
        emailChecked = true;
        $('form[name=register]').submit();
    })
    .fail(function()
    {
        $('#message').html("Something went wrong!");
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to bind .$ajax to event which will trigger it... it runs asynchronously(in the background), and it is used to be triggered by events, not straight away - that is producing your error.  I, also, would change the call for controller to relative path(if your view file is in users, then go 'process/checkemail.php'). Like you did in form's action.

And second - it is better to keep js in separate file.

Also, maybe add some regular expressions to check if that is an email before comparing it to database...

Since you are new to AJAX, you might want to read this article and get yourself familiar with what you are using here, there is an example made for what you need :

http://metaphorical-lab.com/blog/?p=352

and check references for ajax, post and get functions oj jQuery website...

Comment: +1; Thanks, very useful. I've now shifted my script into another file. I've also got some crude checking in the Java script that prevents a submit being performed if it doesn't look like an email address.

Comment: You're welcome, also, I do not know if I provided it in the article, but here is widely tested and well working function for checking email validity:

`function isEmail(Mail)
{
Mail=Mail.toLowerCase();
return (Mail.search( /^[a-zA-Z]+([_\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/) != -1);
}` It return True or False based on inputed text, so just go `if(isEmail(yourvar){...}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this and reply if you face issue
In checkemail.php you will have email by defining $email = $_post['email'];
then verify it and at the end echo response.
response will be show in success section

```
function checkEmail() {
var email = $('#email').val();
$.ajax({           
            type: "POST",  
            url:"/user/process/checkemail.php",  
            data:"email="+email,

            beforeSend: function()
            {                   
                //show some gif img
            },
            success: function(response)
            {               
                   $('#message').html(response);
            }, 

            complete: function()
            {
                //hide gif img
            },

            error: function(e)
            {  
                 alert('Error: ' + e);  
            }  

    }); //end Ajax
}//end function

<div id="register-form">
    <form name="register" action="" method="post" >
        <div class="register-email-cell">
            <p class="text">Email Address</p>
        </div>
    <div class="register-email-cell">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="register-email-cell">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Register" onsubmit="return checkEmail();">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p id="message" class="text"></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    you have to use ajax like that


      function checkEmail()
            {
 $.ajax({
         url: "/user/process/checkemail.php",
        data: { 'email': $('#email').val() },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",

        success: function (result) {
           $('#message').html(response);
        },
        failed: function (d) {
            $('#message').html("Something went wrong!");
                    return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: No, he doesn't. Modern jQuery's `$.ajax()` returns a promise, which is what the asker is using instead of the obsolete callback-style handlers.

Comment: I did try using `success:` and `error:`, but the code in these blocks never seemed to trigger, hence why I switched to using `.done` and `.fail`

Answer (score -1):

This isn't going to the best answer as it doesn't explain why that isn't working. I find it easier just to use jQuery's .load() instead.

Your code would be:

```
 function checkEmail()
{
    email = $('#email').val();
    $('#message').load('/user/process/checkemail.php', {'email' : email});
}
```

This will load the response of the php script straight into the element with ID div. The {'email' : email} part, will pass a $_POST['email'] variable to the script with the value of email.

Comment: So the form is never going to be submitted.

Answer (score -1):

after

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data:
    {
        email: $('#email').val()
    },
    url: "/user/process/checkemail.php"

     success: function(data) {
         $('.result').html(data);
         alert('Load was performed.');
     }  
})
```